# Java how to sort string array based on order values were placed?

Tags: arrays, string

**How can I sort an array and print the values in descending order?**

say the example array is:  `["1a","1b","1c"]`

they have numbers before the first character alphabet values, i want to print:

```
1c
1b
1a
```

Comment: If it's a question of printing only, you might as well sort and then loop from last index to first when printing.

Comment: well its kinda specific to the pattern of the strings i need to do this with and they are being added in different orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What you are asking is to sort an array in reverse order.**

Basically you do this by reversing Arrays.sort() which is ascending.

```
String [] testArray = {"1a", "1b", "1c"};

Arrays.sort(testArray, Collections.reverseOrder());

for (String str : testArray) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output is,

```
1c
1b
1a
```

You can test this here, https://ideone.com/q1OGBD.